# Having issue with text display on html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I have been building my website of a template site I got and have been adding some code to it, that all works fine although one piece, of the html code is failing me which is a text pop-out / rollover effect, It displays fine when I open the index.html file on my browser

[image]

see the YouTube circle although when I upload it to my web server  (I did clear my cache) I get this and then other funky stuff i.e. the text goes very tiny

[image]

I have tried everything I can think of such as re-uploading everything to my server, just the html files and I have even checked my code it is all the same yet it makes things go strange.

Any help is much thanked for,

~Dave~

Comment: sorry question is not clear

Comment: It's pretty clear to me, he doesn't have the same display in local than in his server. I just have no idea why it's doing that... Maybe look at the network, have you tried Ctrl+F5 to remove navigator cache?

Comment: and you will never find out if there is no code provided ;)

Comment: Yes that is quite true I can attach a copy of my index page for you all to look at? as all I do is upload it to the server since it worked fine in opera, firefox, chrome, and dream weaver cc

Comment: just show us the part where you create the circle. Html and css

Comment: there is no CSS to this code it is all done in the hedder, check the mediafire link my code is too long

Comment: delete cache, probably some CSS mistaken

Comment: in chrome it looks like you want... if you are using chrome... see cache, sometimes it not really emptys it. https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95582

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried Ctrl+F5 to remove the navigator cache?
It shows properly on my navigator.

Comment: Oh my days Thank you and @TooJuniorToCode and to everyone else love you all on here.